# calculus quesiton about area of the region

Tags: calculus

sketch the region bounded by the graph of the given function between the indicated values of X.

$f(x)= \dfrac{x^2}3$ ,  $g(x)= x^{1/3}$,     $-1 < x < 1$

Comment: Hello! Could you show your work please? You will be more likely to get help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [gnuplot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnuplot) to sketch both functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. With the following commands

```
gnuplot> set xrange [-1:1]
gnuplot> set yrange [-1:1]
gnuplot> plot x**2.0/3, sgn(x)*exp(log(abs(x))/3)
```

You get

[image: diagram]

Note that I used the formula $x^{1/3} = \operatorname{sgn}(x) \cdot \exp\left(\frac{\log(|x|)}3\right)$ where $\operatorname{sgn}(\cdot)$ is the [signum function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signum_function).